# Can I choose the open Wi-Fi channel?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

My MBP's Wifi connection is very slow. How can I know if I am connected to the best available channel and can I choose the one channel instead another?

I do not have access to this "public" router.

This is what Wifi Diagnostic tool looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the data rat between your Mac and the base station? What does slow mean in terms of an objective measurement? Best is for planning what channel to add next and you aren't likely going to be adding another transmitter if you don't have access to the current base stations, no?

Answer (score 1):

you can't select the frequency that you connect to any specific router to unless you have access to the router.

It's like (literally) "can I access my favorite radio station on 88.5 instead of 102.7?" It is the base station that determines the frequency (channel) it transmits/receives at.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, my question is how can change the channel my connects automatically: there are a lot of channels available. The second question - how can I now if some channel is overcrowded

Comment: You can't. the base station determines the channel(s) it uses not the device that connects to it. iStumbler will list all the locally accessible WiFi channels in use. You can set your base station to use a channel that is less utilized than others.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not access the router settings via ip address? If you can't then there is no way, I'm pretty sure of that.